# How to fix the dropdown in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Code:-

```
const [isActive, SetisActive] = useState(false);
  <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>

                                        <div className="Dropdown">
                                            <div className="Dropdown_btn" onClick={(e) => SetisActive(!isActive)}>{playdata.ChannelName}</div>
                                            {isActive && (
                                                Channelname.map((val, id) => {
                                                    {
                                                        return (
                                                            <Fragment key={id}>
                                                                {removeRedundant([...val, playdata.ChannelName]).map((val1) => {
                                                                    return (
                                                                        <div className="dropdown_content">
                                                                            <div className="dropdown_item"
                                                                             onClick={(e) => { setPlayer(val1, playdata.idx, StoreIdx) }}>{val1}</div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    )
                                                                })}
                                                            </Fragment>
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                })
                                            )}
                                        </div>    
                                    </td>
```

when i click the dropdown_btn every table row show the Dropdow_item list so how can i fix this. that when user click in first row only first row item is shown

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep a map of id to isActive instead of 1 isActive variable.

```
{
 1: true,
 2: false,
 ...
}
```

Define a state

```
const [rowsActive, setRowActive] = useState({})
```

then you can update the state like this:

```
setRowActive(rowsActive => ({...rowsActive, [id]: true}))
```

Comment: can you plz give me some example/code